# Evaluating a limit problem

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

**Problem:** Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ be a continuous function. Assume that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^m}=1,\ \ m\in\Bbb N$$ Show that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{m+1}{x^{m+1}}\int\limits_0^xf(y)\, \mathrm{d}y=1.$$

**Solution:** Given $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^m}=1$$ implies that for any $\varepsilon>0$, $\exists\alpha>0$ such that $\forall x>\alpha$ $$\left|\frac{f(x)}{x^m}-1\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}2\implies |f(x)-x^m|<\frac{\varepsilon}2x^m.$$ Now $$\left|\frac{m+1}{x^{m+1}}\int\limits_0^xf(y)\, \mathrm{d}y-1\right|=\left|\frac{m+1}{x^{m+1}}\left(\int\limits_0^\alpha f(y)\, \mathrm{d}y+\int\limits_\alpha^xf(y)\, \mathrm{d}y\right)-1\right|\leq\left|\frac{m+1}{x^{m+1}}\int\limits_0^\alpha f(y)\, \mathrm{d}y\right|+\left|\frac{m+1}{x^{m+1}}\int\limits_\alpha^xf(y)\, \mathrm{d}y-1\right|.$$ Since $f$ is continuous, $\exists M>0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in[0,\alpha]$. So $$\left|\frac{m+1}{x^{m+1}}\int\limits_0^xf(y)\, \mathrm{d}y-1\right|\leq\frac{m+1}{x^{m+1}}\int\limits_0^\alpha|f(y)|\, \mathrm{d}y+\left|\frac{m+1}{x^{m+1}}\int\limits_\alpha^x(f(y)-y^m)\, \mathrm{d}y\right|+\frac{\alpha^{m+1}}{x^{m+1}}$$$$\leq\frac{M\alpha(m+1)+\alpha^{m+1}}{x^{m+1}}+\frac{m+1}{x^{m+1}}\int\limits_\alpha^x|f(y)-y^m|\, \mathrm{d}y<\frac{M\alpha(m+1)+\alpha^{m+1}}{x^{m+1}}+\frac{m+1}{x^{m+1}}\int\limits_\alpha^x\frac{\varepsilon}2y^m\, \mathrm{d}y<\frac{M\alpha(m+1)}{x^{m+1}}+1+\frac{\varepsilon}2(1-\frac{\alpha^{m+1}}{x^{m+1}})<\varepsilon$$ for all $x>\max\left\{\alpha,\left(\frac{2M\alpha(m+1)}{\varepsilon-2}\right)^{\frac1{m+1}}\right\}$.

Thus $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{m+1}{x^{m+1}}\int\limits_0^xf(y)\, \mathrm{d}y=1.$$

Kindly check this solution and correct it if there is any flaw.

Thank you.

Comment: Just use L'Hôpital's rule with the second fundamental theorem of calculus..?

Comment: @Ty. how do you know the numerator goes to infinity, as to justify the use of L'Hoptial's?

Comment: @NicholasRoberts  Well how else would the second limit equal $1$?

Comment: @Ty. I see, so $f(x)$ goes to infinity as $x \to \infty$ and thus the improper integral in the numerator must diverge?

Comment: @AnishRay Why is it not $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$?  The denominator clearly equals $\infty$ and the numerator should also.  For the second limit to equal $1$, $\int_0^x f(y) \; dy$ must, too, equal $\infty$.  Also, there are more indeterminate forms than just those two.

Comment: @Ty. Yes there are definitely other indeterminate forms. I clearly mentioned the cases only when L'Hospitals is generally used. Now you cannot assume that the numerator goes to $\infty$. If you can show it then only you can use it to solve the problem.

Comment: @AnishRay I didn't assume the numerator goes to $\infty$.  $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}= \int_0^x f(y) \; dy$ and given $m \geq 1$, clearly the left side equals $\infty$.

Comment: @Ty. You are assuming the result to be proven

Comment: Oh I see, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

We are looking at

$$\tag 1 \frac{\int_0^x f(y)\,dy}{x^{m+1}/(m+1)}.$$

Now as $x\to \infty,$ the denominator $\to \infty.$ We are in the indeterminate form $\dfrac{?}{\infty}.$ Thus we can apply L'Hospital! For some strange reason a lot of students don't know this form of L'Hopital. It's just as easy to prove as the $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ case.

Well, OK, suppose you don't know this and you're mired in the $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ cult. You could proceed as Ty was trying to do. From the hypotheses, we know there exists $a>0$ such that $f(x)/x^m >1/2$ for $x>a.$ Thus for $x>a,$

$$\int_0^x f(y)\,dy > \int_a^x f(y)\,dy$$ $$>\int_a^x (1/2)y^m\,dy = \frac{x^{m+1}-a^{m+1}}{2(m+1)}.$$

The last term above $\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty.$ So the numerator in $(1)$ $\to \infty$ and "regular" L'Hopital applies.

Comment: Hi @zhw. Can you explain to me why this reasoning doesn't work to assert that the numerator tends to infinity. From the assumption $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^m}=1$, it implies that $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. Thus, the improper integral $\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_0^x f(t) dt$ necessarily diverges.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts I find that convincing, but I found a comment you made confusing, where you said Ty was assuming what was to be proven.

Comment: +1 and we need more efforts to popularize that L'Hospital's Rule works on "$\text{anything} /\infty $".

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Someone downvoted, hilarious.

Comment: Well that proves my point. Need to popularize... :) :)